# Why is TextBlock.FontSize converted into an attached property in binary (BAML)?

Tags: wpf, attached-properties, baml

This XAML source:

```
<TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="16" />
```

is compiled to BAML, according to ILSpy:

```
<TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" TextBlock.FontSize="16" />
```

I may be wrong but it seems the BAML version uses the attached property syntax instead of the property syntax (used for example for `Margin`).

I found:

- This related question [How is the attached property TextBlock.FontSize used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6919263/774575) says:

  > `TextBlock.FontSize` is not an attached property, it's just a regular 
  >   dependency property

which may be somehow contradictory with [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textblock.fontsize):

- > This dependency property also has an attached property usage. In XAML,
  >   the usage is <object TextBlock.FontSize="value".../>, where object is
  >   an object element (typically a flow element) contained within a
  >   TextBlock [...]

What is the correct explanation for this syntax difference between `Margin` and `FontSize` assignments in BAML?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/TextBlock.cs,93ba7392b999a01c). There is:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty FontSizeProperty =
    TextElement.FontSizeProperty.AddOwner(typeof(TextBlock));

public double FontSize
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(FontSizeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(FontSizeProperty, value); }
}
```

with `TextElement.FontSizeProperty` defined like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty FontSizeProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "FontSize",
        typeof(double),
        typeof(TextElement),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            SystemFonts.MessageFontSize,
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure |
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender |
            FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Inherits),
        new ValidateValueCallback(IsValidFontSize));
```

So while `FontSize` is not supposed to be used as an attached property, its identifier field is initialized by calling `AddOwner` on the identifier field of an attached property.

Just my guess, but I think that from this aspect `TextBlock.FontSize` is treated as an attached property.